# sinatra session members disappear when set while streaming

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

If I have this code in my sinatra handler:

```
get '/foo' do
  session[:message] = 'hello world'

  stream {|out|
    out << session[:message]
  }
end

get '/bar' do
  session[:message]
end
```

then both URL respond with `hello world` (`/bar` being visited after `/foo`). If I move the session initialization code inside the `stream` call as shown below, then `/foo` responds with `hello world` as before, but `/bar` responds with the empty string.

is this a bug? how to make sure that when I set a session variable inside my streaming block it gets read correctly in other handlers?

```
get '/foo' do
  stream {|out|
    session[:message] = 'hello world';
    out << session[:message]
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions work as middleware. When the request comes in the current sessions variables (if any) are read in from wherever they are stored and made available to the rest of the request as a hash. When the request is finished, the middleware persists this hash to whatever session store is being used and the appropriate headers are set on the response. (I’m simplifying somewhat here, but this is basically what happens).

When streaming, the block to `stream` is called *after* the response is finished, i.e. after the session middleware has run. This means that although the `session` hash is still available, and you can set items on it, it is never persisted anywhere and so anything you set here isn’t available in any later requests.

If you are using the default cookie based session store there is little you can do here other than make sure you set your session variables outside the `stream` block. By the time the `stream` block is called, all the headers have been written out including the cookie containing the serialized session data.

If you are using a server side session store you could alter the session code so that late updates such as these are persisted. Whether it would be worth it would be another question.

Comment: thanks. Interesting. I make an HTTP call to an external service to register a user, which returns me the ID of the newly created user, which effectively logs in this user, so I need to store this ID in my session... I can make this call without using streaming but then it will hold other requests (at least on the same thread), am I correct? I am not sure if I have to use streaming to make a call like this from my route handler...